# Aligning side-by-side DIV elements with auto height and floating on even/odd

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve a "side-by-side" box where two divs are inside a container side by side (floating left and right). However, I want the divs to change from right to left and left to right per every box, while still maintaining the height on both divs as the content grows.

My HTML is static. I cannot change this. You will see that the left divs contain text, and the right divs contain a background image and some text:

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="boxes">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="text">
            This is some content<br>
            This is some content<br>
            This is some content<br>
            This is some content<br>
            This is some content<br>
            This is some content<br>
        </div>
        <div class="image">Right</div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="text">
            This is some content<br>
        </div>
        <div class="image">Right</div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="text">
            This is some content<br>
            This is some content<br>
            This is some content<br>
        </div>
        <div class="image">Right</div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="text">
            This is some content<br>
            This is some content<br>
            This is some content<br>
            This is some content<br>
            This is some content<br>
            This is some content<br>
        </div>
        <div class="image">Right</div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="text">
            This is some content<br>
            This is some content<br>
            This is some content<br>
        </div>
        <div class="image">Right</div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I initially tried the following CSS (without the comments):

```
<style>
    #boxes {
        width: 500px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .box {
        margin: 5px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        /*display: flex;*/
        width: 100%;
    }

    .box .text {
        width: 50%;
        background-color: #ccc;
        /*flex: 1;*/
    }

    .box .image {
        width: 50%;
        background-color: #eee;
        /*flex: 1;*/
        background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1/);
    }

    .box:nth-child(even) .text {
        float: left;
    }

    .box:nth-child(even) .image {
        float: right;
    }

    .box:nth-child(odd) .text {
        float: right;
    }

    .box:nth-child(odd) .image {
        float: left;
    }
</style>
```

Which resulted in this:
[image]

Which is almost there, except the picture is not showing because theres nothing telling the `.image` div to grow as the text grows in the `.text` div so then I added the `flex` CSS (remove the comments in the above CSS) and it resulted in this:
[image]

Now the image shows (which is what I want) but the floats are not working.

Heres a **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/a0h89ond/)**. Please let me know if anyone knows what Im missing.

*PS: No Javascript is allowed*

Thanks.

Comment: @FelipeAlarcon Thanks. I am trying to use Flexbox as you can see in my CSS code comments. Am I doing that correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need floats if you use flexbox.

Just reverse the order every odd box with `flex-flow: row-reverse;`

```css
#boxes {
        width: 500px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .box {
        margin: 5px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .box .text {
        width: 50%;
        background-color: #ccc;
        flex: 1;
    }

    .box .image {
        width: 50%;
        background-color: #eee;
        flex: 1;
        background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1/);
    }

    .box:nth-child(odd) {
        flex-flow:row-reverse;
    }
```

```html
<div id="boxes">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="text">
            This is some content<br>
            This is some content<br>
            This is some content<br>
            This is some content<br>
            This is some content<br>
            This is some content<br>
        </div>
        <div class="image">Right</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="text">
            This is some content<br>
        </div>
        <div class="image">Right</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="text">
            This is some content<br>
            This is some content<br>
            This is some content<br>
        </div>
        <div class="image">Right</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="text">
            This is some content<br>
            This is some content<br>
            This is some content<br>
            This is some content<br>
            This is some content<br>
            This is some content<br>
        </div>
        <div class="image">Right</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="text">
            This is some content<br>
            This is some content<br>
            This is some content<br>
        </div>
        <div class="image">Right</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great, this is exactly what I was going to write, good answer.

Comment: This looks promising, I will try it out. Can you explain why floats dont work with flexbox?

Comment: @CodeGodie you may want to read this article [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Thank you. I learned something new. I will also read that article to learn more about it.

Comment: @CodeGodie, floats don't work with flexbox because in a [*flex formatting context*](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-containers) (as per the spec) floats are ignored. This is a key difference between a flex and block formatting context. Another difference is that in a FFC, margins don't collapse. https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-containers

Comment: @Michael_B thanks for pointing that out. Yeah, I thought that was the case. I will read more on FFC.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/jameson5555/oj2qv81m/1/

I switched to absolute positioning for the images, and then adjusted even images like this:

```
.box:nth-child(even) .image {
  left: 50%;
  right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh yeah you're close. You're simply missing 
`flex-direction: row-reverse`

Add it to your even boxes instead of relying on floats.

```
.box:nth-child(2n+1) {
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o5rypunn/